# log4net properties with parameters

Tags: c#, properties, log4net

I'd like to set a new custom property in log4net.GlobalContext.
This property should depend on a given parameter, like:

```
<appender name="MainLog" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
      <param name="Encoding" value="Unicode" />
      <param name="File" value="Logs\{MyProperty(SOME_VALUE)}log" />
```

so the log's name will be different if a different value is assigned to SOME_VALUE.

Can it be done? and if so - how?

Comment: You have full control to the final value so why do you want log4net to do something this strange?

Comment: I guess I don't know exactly what to search. I didn't find anything :/

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? RollingFileAppender can already take care of renaming historical files and to log in differently named files just register a dedicated appender with the desired output file name.

Comment: @Filburt: I need to name the log file according to a value in the registry on the user's computer. I'd like the registry key to be given as a parameter because it might change some day and I don't want it to be hard coded.

Comment: I wouldn't call a value configured in your log4net config hardcoded. You could update it whenever your registry value changes or reconcile on application startup.

Comment: @Filburt: yes, so I want to make a property that can read from the registry and the registry key should be its parameter which will be set in the configuration file. The problem is that I can't find an example for this...

Comment: Is that Key something the end user will be willing to change? You can just add a sepparate web.config for your log4net section where the user can easily configure the name/path of the file? Don't know if that helps or if it's an option for you

Comment: @MarioGarcia: The user can change this value but its an "expert" user so it doesn't have to be very user friendly :)

Comment: Is it a value that will change very often? I would suggest you what I mentioned. Take the log4net configuration on a sepparate web.config, so whenever the user needs to change that value will be easy to find and won't have to navigate through the full web.config of your application. Not sure if I'm explaining well. Look here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/140911/log-net-Tutorial (section "Getting Away from app.config/web.config"). Feel free to ask if anything is unclear